# An error ['\+' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\+" while creating a R package

Tags: macos, r, package, x11

I tried to create a package using some functions and scripts I created (using X11 on a Mac). While R CMD check was doing its work, it encountered a problem as follows:

```
temp = trim(unlist(strsplit(lp.add(ranefterms[[i]]), 
+                     "\+")))
Error: '\+' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\+"
```

The oddest thing, however, is that my function actually does NOT have "\ +". Instead, it has "\ \ +" (see below). So I don't know why "\ \ +" is recognized as "\ +".

```
for(i in 1:n)
   temp = trim(unlist(strsplit(lp.add(ranefterms[[i]]), '\\+')))
```

To dig a little further, I looked at the packageName-Ex.R file in the Rcheck folder. As it turned out, all the "\ \"s have been changed to "\" in the checking process (e.g., the double slashes I need for functions such as strsplit() and grepl())

I wonder what may have been the cause of it. Sorry that I can't come up with a reproducible example...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The offending code comes from the Examples section of one of your help files (which is why it ends up in `packageName-Ex.R`).  To fix it, just escape each of the backslashes in the Examples sections of your `*.Rd` documentation files with a second backslash. (So, type `\\`to get `\` in the processed help file, and type `\\\\` to get `\\`.)

Unless it's escaped, `\` is interpreted as a special character that identifies sectioning and mark-up macros (i.e. commands like `\author`, `\description`, `\bold`, and `\ldots`). Quoting from Duncan Murdoch's [**Parsing Rd files**](http://developer.r-project.org/parseRd.pdf) (the official manual for this topic):

> The backslash \ is used as an escape character: \, \%, { and }
>   remove the special meaning of the second character.

As an example of what this looks like in practice, here is part of `$R_SOURCE_HOME/src/library/base/man/grep.Rd`, which is processed to create the help file you see when you type `?grep` or `?gsub`.

```
## capitalizing
txt <- "a test of capitalizing"
gsub("(\\\\w)(\\\\w*)", "\\\\U\\\\1\\\\L\\\\2", txt, perl=TRUE)
gsub("\\\\b(\\\\w)",    "\\\\U\\\\1",       txt, perl=TRUE)
```

In the processed help file, it looks like this:

```
 ## capitalizing
 txt <- "a test of capitalizing"
 gsub("(\\w)(\\w*)", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", txt, perl=TRUE)
 gsub("\\b(\\w)",    "\\U\\1",       txt, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: @Josh-obrien Thanks. The help file was indeed the problem. Do you know why this is a problem? I created a package in the past and did not encounter a similar problem - I didn't change any of "\\"s to "\\\\"s.

Comment: @X.He -- This isn't something new, so I'll bet your earlier package didn't have any `\\ ` in your examples, **or** that any examples were inside of a `\dontrun{}` block, **or** that you didn't run R CMD check. Remember, this is not a problem having to do with the code in any of your packaged functions. Instead, it's to do with the way `*.Rd` files are processed.