# Is it possible to escape "[" in R

Tags: r, escaping

```
 a = list("a","b","cdef", "[")
 grep("a",a)
 #[1] 1
 grep("[",a)
 #Error during wrapup: invalid regular expression '[', reason 'Missing ']''
 grep('\[',a)
 #Error during wrapup: '\[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\["
 grep("\[",a)
 #Error during wrapup: '\[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\["
 grep("\133",a)
 #Error during wrapup: invalid regular expression '[', reason 'Missing ']''
```

I thought to do the "\133" based on information found here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Literal-constants unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: did you search? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex) or  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695879/error-r-is-an-unrecognized-escape-in-character-string-starting-c-r) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605485/an-error-is-an-unrecognized-escape-in-character-string-starting-while)

Comment: There is a remaining question regarding why you are using a pattern that will match none of your test items.

Comment: It makes sense now... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `grep()` uses regular expressions and `[` is a special character in regular expression, you can either disable regular expressions with

```
grep("[", a, fixed=TRUE)
```

or escape the `[` by doing

```
grep("\\[", a)
```

Note the double slash here because the correct regular expression syntax would be `\[` but you also need to escape the slash in the R string since you want a literal slash and not an escape code so it becomes `\\[`